# Error importing DLL using python.ctypes on Cygwin

Tags: python, cygwin, ctypes

I am using Cygwin (2.2.1) on wind7 to run a python script that loads a dll and I tried using cdll form ctypes. However I get OSError: Exec format error when I run the script, and I do not know how to deal with it. I also tried giving the path to the file, but the issue seems to be elsewhere.

```
>>> from ctypes import * 
>>> cdll.LoadLibrary("DECO_CalInterface.dll")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DECOInitialization.py", line 18, in <module>
    cdll.LoadLibrary("DECO_CalInterface.dll")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 443, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: Exec format error
```

Comment: Have you checked your library format *i.e.* x32 or x64?